# SQL query errors and mistakes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue with a SQL query.

The question: show all the departments in which the max salary is bigger than 10000.

I am getting an output with this but it doesn't seem right.

My code:

```
SELECT 
   Department_Name, Max_Salary
FROM
   Departments
INNER JOIN 
   Job_History ON Departments.department_id = Job_History.department_id
INNER JOIN 
   Jobs ON Job_History.job_id = jobs.job_id
WHERE 
   Max_Salary > 10000
```

Output:

```
DEPT_NAME  | MAX_SALARY
------------------------
Accounting | 16,000
Sales      | 12,080   
Sales      | 20,080
```

There is only one Sales department in the database.

Any help on why this is happening would be appreciated.

Comment: can you just go to the individual tables and get the dept with max salary ? Check the dept names carefully.

Comment: I assume Max_Salary is from either Job_History or Jobs and that, in the case of the Sales department, more than one row from those tables applies, hence you see Sales more than once in the output. You may need to sum the Max_Salary and use Group By and Having clauses. If you can show us the relevant data in the tables, it'll allow us to provide a decent answer for you.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev I can't unfortunately as Department_Name is in dbo.Departments, dbo.Job_History links Departments and Jobs through the department_id key. Max_Salary is in the Jobs table with the Job _ID which links both Job_History and Jobs. I have to link 3 tables. Which I have done. I have tried what NigelK suggested and have had some success, but its still displaying only 3 departments no duplicates, but I think think more rows should be affected.

Answer (score 3):

Likely, there are multiple rows in `job_history` that are related to 'Sales' Department.

The join operation is returning *all* matching rows.

To get a distinct list of Department_Name, you could add **`GROUP BY Department_name`** to the end of the query. You'll also want to use an aggregate function around the `Max_Salary` column in the select list... e.g.  `MAX(Max_Salary)`.

Best practice is to qualify *all* column references in the query. For a reader not familiar with the database schema, it's not clear whether `Max_Salary` is from the `Job_History` table, or the `Job` table.  Also, the keyword `INNER` has no effect on the join operation, that keyword can be omitted.

--This works

```
SELECT d.department_name
     , MAX(j.max_salary) AS max_salary
  FROM Departments d
  JOIN Job_History h
    ON h.department_id = d.department_id
  JOIN Jobs j
    ON j.job_id = h.job_id
 WHERE j.max_salary > 10000
 GROUP BY d.department_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to comment, but I don't have a high enough reputation.

Can you try this and see what it brings for the ids.

```
Select Department_Name, Max_Salary,D.department_id,J.job_id
From Departments D
INNER JOIN Job_History J_H
ON D.department_id=J_H.department_id
INNER JOIN Jobs J
ON J_H.job_id=J.job_id
WHERE Max_Salary > 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select d.department_name
 , MAX(j.max_salary) AS max_salary
From Departments D
INNER JOIN Job_History J_H
ON D.department_id=J_H.department_id
INNER JOIN Jobs J
ON J_H.job_id=J.job_id
GROUP BY d.department_name
having max(j.max_salary)>10000
```

Comment: This answer could be improved with some comments... what was incorrect with the code in the question? How does your code get around that? Nonetheless, I'm marking this as "Looks OK" in response to a flag someone else raised on it.